# Как нажать кнопку Enter в Winium

Tags: test-automation, desktop

Доброго времени суток!

Недавно начал работать с winium desktop. Наткнулся на одну проблему. Нужно в TextBox написать имя и фамилию, а после нажать enter чтобы textBox сработал,но это не работает.
Я пытался нажать enter при помощи вот этой команды :

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

но не сработало,он просто завершает тест.
Далее пытался добавить enter прямо в TextBox,но это приводило к тому что данные введеные до этого просто стирались и TextBox был пуст.
Прошу у вас помощи так как нигде нет нормальный туториалов